# Hbase table column value not able to update- if variable having NaN

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, hbase, nan, column-family

I am not able to update the value in hbase column family. 
The condition is - If variable cricketScore is not a number then update the value as "NA", otherwise update the value.

```
  cricketScore= 100F // isNaN -- > false
 // cricketScore = 0.0/0.0                                        // isNaN -- > true

 hTable.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cricket"), Bytes.toBytes("cricket_score"), Bytes.toBytes(cricketScore.isNaN ? "NA" : cricketScore.toString))
```

I am getting below error:

> Cannot resolve overloaded method 'toBytes'
>
> Cannot resolve symbol ?
>
> Cannot resolve symbol cricketScore

May, I know the reason? and how to resolve this?